# URL encoding issue: different results between two servers

Tags: php, codeigniter, urlencode

I have two servers, they both have same configurations. I uploaded same code into both servers.

```
<?php

echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
exit;

?>
```

When I access server 1 `http://server1.com/%3d`

it prints `/%3d`

When I access server 2 `http://server2.com/%3d`

it prints `/=`

What cause this in different results?

Is there any setting I can do? or anyway to detect it?

Comment: Which are the version of both servers? It seems that one of them is decoding the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **[urldecode()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.urldecode.php)**

```
<?php 

$server1 = '/%3d';
$server2 = '/=';

print urldecode($server1); // is /=
print urldecode($server2); // is also /=
```

Eg. `print urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

[Example Codepad here](http://codepad.org/pL5i04m9)

Comment: Thanks Bradley, is it possible to tell me what cause this? or any setting I can change it's behavior?

Cuz my situation is more complex than this. for example I need to access this

`http://server1.com/controller_name/edit/9SuBLAy9j%2Fmld4s%2Bqh0Hyav88%2B4wofFE1iz8acXrECkJysYzF2WM6xLLGYANpc8Oa1EM%2Fb50KuaUOhDGfTDZawX8OeRRjAmxmz%2FNJ14SC1ctb6GK45UN12CdiOhRB8n%2B`

And in CodeIgniter with URL rewrite

    public function edit($param)
    {
        echo $param;
    }

I get 

`9SuBLAy9j`

only cuz `%2F` is `/`

Comment: Why don't you set it as a query parameter? `/controller_name/edit/?edit=9SuBLAy9j%2Fmld4s%2Bqh0Hyav....` and then grab that in php with `$_GET['edit']`